# "en" in "une seule histoire en de multiples épisodes"

Tags: prépositions

I was reading an answer on [this page](https://hinative.com/questions/15294817) and came across this line. I don't quite understand
"en"'s function in this sentence. "A story *of* multiple episodes"? or "A story told *in* multiple episodes"? Could I see some similar examples with "en" used in the same sense?

Comment: The sentence _une seule histoire en de multiples épisodes_ just means "a single story with multiple episodes". The use of _en_ here is dated, IMHO.

Comment: @Frank I don't think the use of *en* is outdated here. The normal use of *en* in front of a numeral, I consider *multiple* to be a numeral here, since we could have any numeral here instead.

Comment: @None _Une histoire en trois parties_, pas de problème. Mais _en de multiples épisodes_, ça passe moins bien quand même.

Comment: @desmo what puzzles you here? *en de* or just *en*? The latter has a direct equivalent in English: "a story in 4 parts", "a play in 3 acts", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of *en* in the sentence you are referring to is one of the usual use of *en*.  "Of" is only one of the numerous meanings of this preposition, and here "of" doesn't fit.
"A story told in multiple episodes" is a possible translation. Another possibility would be "A story divided into multiple episodes".

In this sentence *en*  expresses division. It is the same *en* that is used after verbs like *diviser*, *partager*, *répartir*...

- *Divisons le gâteau en cinq parts.* → Let's divide the cake into five pieces.
- *Répartissons-nous en plusieurs groupes*. →  Let's split into several groups.

The preposition *en* has several different meanings, I'll only give a few examples, this is by no means an exhaustive list:

- *Des sabots en bois.* → Clogs *made of* wood (or possibly wooden clogs).
- *Voyager en train.* → To travel *by* plane.
- *Je mangerai en route.* → I'll have lunch *on* the way.

---

<sub>As a side note I'd like to add that for some French people (at least in France) the difference between *feuilleton* and *série* is not so clear cut as said in the sentence you are pointing to. It is often a generation thing (*feuilleton* sounding old fashioned, *série* being a more recent word in the broadcasting world, most likely borrowed from English in this sense).</sub>

Comment: Right, or "made up of / consisting in" multiple episodes. The *de* here would also be confusing if one didn't know that *des* typically becomes *de* before an adjective, which makes it look like a second preposition after *en* rather than the partitive article that it actually is.

Comment: Le "problème" ici, c'est le _de_ après le _en_, à mon avis. _En plusieurs épisodes_ aurait été plus courant.

Comment: @Frank Moi, je ne le dirais pas, mais, doutant avant de le mentionner dans la réponse (bien que la question ne portait pas sur ça) j'ai entré  "en de multiples épisodes" dans un moteur de recherches et le nombre d'occurrences étant nombreuses, et dans des publications de qualité (presse et articles universitaires),  j'ai préféré ne rien dire.